# Importing data from the Firebase does not appear in the textview

Tags: java, android

The data from the Realtime Database Firebase does not appear in textview. I've looked for similar problems here, but I haven't solved them. I'd appreciate it if you could help me solve this problem.

firebase structure:

```
  "state" : {
    "open_close" : "open",
    "weight" : 2500
  }
```

java code:

```
public class SubActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tvWeight;
    TextView tvOpen_close;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub);

        tvWeight = findViewById(R.id.textView_weight);
        tvOpen_close = findViewById(R.id.textView_open_close);

        final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("state");

        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    String value = dataSnapshot.child("open_close").getValue(String.class);
                    int weight = dataSnapshot.child("weight").getValue(int.class);

                    tvWeight.setText(weight);
                    tvOpen_close.setText(value);
                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) { ... } }

Answer (score 2):

There is no need of for loop ,you can directly access it like this.

```
public class SubActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tvWeight;
    TextView tvOpen_close;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub);

        tvWeight = findViewById(R.id.textView_weight);
        tvOpen_close = findViewById(R.id.textView_open_close);

        final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("state");

        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String value = dataSnapshot.child("open_close").getValue(String.class);
                    int weight = dataSnapshot.child("weight").getValue(int.class);

                    tvWeight.setText(weight);
                    tvOpen_close.setText(value);

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String value = snapshot.child("open_close").getValue(String.class);
int weight = snapshot.child("weight").getValue(Integer.class);
```

You are already iterating over children from your snapshot. You don't need to get to the parent snapshot to get child values. Use the iterated value of your snapshot and get values from it. Change your code to above.

**Edit**

Also if you don't have many nodes same as `state` I don't see any point of iterating over children.
If your database contain only one node as

```
`"state" : {
    "open_close" : "open",
    "weight" : 2500
  }`
```

then don't iterate over it. Just call it directly as below:

```
final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            
                String value = dataSnapshot.child("state").child("open_close").getValue(String.class);
                int weight = dataSnapshot.child("state").child("weight").getValue(Integer.class);

                tvWeight.setText(weight);
                tvOpen_close.setText(value);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but even if I modify the code, I still can't see it in the textview...

Comment: Check if you are getting the values inside your listeners. Try to log them.

Comment: Also I found that you are assigning wrong class value to Integer. Instead of `int.class` use `Integer.class`.